# React component not rendering dynamic images with Astro and URL mappings

Tags: reactjs, image, build, vite, astrojs

How i am rendering images dynamically in astro components

```
  import { Image } from "astro:assets";
  import type { ImageMetadata } from "astro";

  const images = import.meta.glob<{ default: ImageMetadata }>(
    "/src/assets/*.{jpeg,jpg,png,gif,avif,jpg,svg,webp}"
  );

const { title, description, resource } = Astro.props;


<Image
            height={24}
            width={24}
            class="rounded-md"
            src={images[resource]()}
            alt={title}
          />
```

This works and compiles into -  http://thundering-knowledge.surge.sh/_astro/default-img.DQCbfkMr_ZEy79V.webp in build

For my react component I had to do this tedious work around

src/assets/Images.jsx

```
const IMAGES = {
    '/src/assets/default-img.webp' : new URL('./default-img.webp', import.meta.url).href,
    '/src/assets/drone.png' : new URL('./drone.png', import.meta.url).href,
    '/src/assets/ImageMetaGenerator.js' : new URL('./ImageMetaGenerator.js', import.meta.url).href,
    '/src/assets/MdiAccessPointNetwork.svg' : new URL('./MdiAccessPointNetwork.svg', import.meta.url).href,
    '/src/assets/MdiCog.svg' : new URL('./MdiCog.svg', import.meta.url).href,
    '/src/assets/MdiEarth.svg' : new URL('./MdiEarth.svg', import.meta.url).href,
    '/src/assets/MdiLightbulb.svg' : new URL('./MdiLightbulb.svg', import.meta.url).href
};
export default IMAGES;
```

for creating an index of the files and so that at build they are "noticed" so the image path can be updated

usage

```
import IMAGES from "@/assets/Images";


const ProductCard: React.FC<Props> = ({
  title,
  description,
  resource,
  href,
})
 => {
return (
 <img
              className="w-full h-auto"
              width="1209"
              height="890"
              loading="lazy"
              decoding="async"
              alt=""
              aria-hidden="true"
              //@ts-ignore
              src={IMAGES[resource]}
            />

)

}
```

This does not work and compiles into - http://thundering-knowledge.surge.sh/_astro/default-img.DQCbfkMr.webp

In both case resource being the image path i.e "/src/assets/img.webp"

astro.config.mjs

```
export default defineConfig({
  integrations: [tailwind({
    applyBaseStyles: false
  }), react(), icon(), compress(), compressor()]
});
```

I feel like this has some thing to do with the astro plugins that are minifying the images used in astro components but not the one in the react components

I tried finding solutions for this but have had no luck so far

Any help is much appreciated , Thank you !